# Maximizing $e^{-x^2/2}\cosh(ax)$

Tags: functions, optimization, maxima-minima, hyperbolic-functions

Consider the function $f_a:\mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ given by
$$
f_a(x) = e^{-x^2/2}\cosh(ax).
$$
It seems that there is a value of $c > 0$ such that for $a \in (0,c)$ the maximum of the function occurs at $0$ and for $a \in (c,\infty)$ the maximum occurs and values $\pm M_a$ where $M_a$ is nonzero. What is that threshold value $c$ (if the above is true)?

Comment: Given that $\cosh$ is an even function, the above seems false since the function is unchanged $f_a \to f_{-a}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

\begin{align}
f_a'(x) & = e^{-x^2/2}(-x)\cosh(ax) + a e^{-x^2/2} \sinh(ax) = 0 \\
& \implies a\tanh(ax) = x.
\end{align}
We may as well consider $a > 0$. Clearly $x = 0$ is always a critical point and note that the LHS approaches $\pm 1$ as $ x \to \pm \infty$. I will leave it to you to show that if $0 < a < 1$ then the above equation only has the solution $x = 0$.

Comment: Very nice. So, I gather you take back your comment above that it is false?

Comment: I do not. Note that I say we may as well consider $a > 0$, that is because $a \to -a$ is a symmetry of the equation. You will also have $-1<a<0$ only have one solution. So actually $|a| < 1$ is the correct condition. My above claim about it being false was that you're missing half the solution.

Comment: OK. $a$ is a parameter and I only asked what happens for $a > 0$ (as you point out, by symmetry, it is enough to assume $a > 0$ as the behavior of the problem for $a < 0$ will be the same as that for $-a$.)